# How to use Windows Forms in the new mac version of Visual Studio

Tags: macos, winforms, visual-studio

So, this summer (June 2017) Visual studio released a Mac version of Visual Studio. Apparently Windows Forms should work with it but I unfortunately have trouble figuring how this could be done.

I have been googling for quite some time now but no one seems to go into how exactly this can be done. I have installed the mac version and when creating a new solution those are the options I get:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since using Windows Forms is a requirement for the project I was assigned to, I can't use the Gtk# project option. I've been playing around with those options, trying to see if I can find anything that will recognize `System.Windows.Forms`, with no luck.

Can it be used on Mac or is this something I still have to use Windows for? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Go back to Windows and use SharpDevelop or Visual Studio.

Comment: That's of course an option but since I only have one computer in my apartment which happens to be a Mac, I would have to either use a public computer for this, run VirtualBox which is very slow or buy a new computer. Since Windows Forms should also work on Mac according to some people on the Internet I am just wondering if anyone knows if it really can (and how) or not.

Comment: Windows Forms on Mono is technically incomplete, and without visual designer. Stop believing everything you get from the internet. And that's probably why Microsoft/Xamarin does not ever show a wizard/template in the IDE.